# Producing 64-bit builds on Windows with free software

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, visual-studio-express

I have a C++ project that I've been developing in Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.  It has come to the point that I'd like to port to 64-bit and continue development.

**What is the best way to do this using free software?**

---

*My thoughts so far:*

The Express Edition of MSVC doesn't come with 64-bit compilers, so I can install the Windows SDK to get these.  I could then port my project files to `nmake`, and use the IDE just as a tool to debug and invoke my `nmak`e scripts..  The downside to this is that `nmake` looks very poor.  The example towards the end of [this tutorial](http://web.sau.edu/lilliskevinm/csci240/masmdocs/envtools/26LMAETC16.pdf) suggests that `nmake` cannot figure out source file dependences itself, and I don't know of anything equivelant to [`gcc -M`](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html#gcc) that I could use.

Another option might be to use `vcbuild` from the Windows SDK to produce 64-bit builds from my existing `vcproj` files.  Preliminary investigations show that this doesn't really work, as my project files don't have the 64-bit configurations present.  (Perhaps I could fudge this by adding the 64-bit configurations to the vcproj files in a text editor.)

A final option might be to give up on MSVC, and port my project to the [MinGW/MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) toolchain.

Comment: What's the problem with using MSVC Express? It can be configured to use the Win SDK compiler. Wouldn't that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *makedepend* as an alternative to *gcc -M*. [Here](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html)'s a primer on this and other methods of generating dependencies.

You could also give the *autoconf+automake* combo a try, though it requires some work to make it use MSVC's compiler. [Some](http://www.mail-archive.com/automake@gnu.org/msg10824.html) have succeded at doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Windows SDK compiler with GNU make or another build system, you could write a program/script that converts the output of [`cl.exe /showIncludes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx) into a format that is compatible with your build system.